# firefox 79 on android CSS position bottom hidden by white bar

Tags: css, firefox, toolbar

I have a page that fits to the screen size of the browser window. It works in any browser, except in the latest firefox 79 for android devices (it worked until the last ff release).

The new firefox release hides the bottom of the page either with its toolbar or (if set to show toolbar on top) with a useless white bar of the same size on the bottom. I have buttons at the bottom that "shine" through that white "hiding bar", but they are not touchable. So, in principle, everything on the page is positioned correctly, except that firefox lays its "hiding bar" or it's toolbar over the bottom, depending on ff settings.

In CSS I have set html,body min-height to 100%. (It doesn't help when set to 100vh)
There's a wrapper div that encloses everything else, set to min-height 100vh.
There's a footer div (inside wrapper) set to position absolute, bottom 0;

Now the page fits the screen size including firefox's "hiding bar", thus part of the footer div is invisible. As the page isn't larger than the screen it cannot be moved up. There is no way to make visible the part of the footer that is overlayed by that white bar...

(If my description isn't clear enough I can provide images)

Anybody knows how I can position something at the bottom of the really visible screen, e.g. just above firefox's "hiding bar"?

Comment: I'm also have the same issue, there's a bug thread https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/8768 but I'm not sure why it's closed since this issue still happens on certain websites

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on current FF mobile on Android. Do you meanwhile have a solution?

Comment: I believe the problem still exists. With toolbar moved to top, my index-page appears full page, but there is a white empty space "attached" to the bottom, so that I can scroll up to make it visible. Scrolling down and up /twice/ makes the white space permanent and my page can only use the remaining screen space. Extremely annoying especially in horizontal view.